# PHPStorm, Docker and debugging

Tags: php, macos, debugging, docker, phpstorm

I'm trying to debug php code with PHPStorm. I'm on a Mac with docker.
I configured xdebug on docker using:

```
zend_extension="/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20151012/xdebug.so"
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_connect_back=1
xdebug.idekey = "PHPSTORM"
```

Then I open the listening on PHPStorm, set the cookie in the browser and then load a page setting a break point in the corresponding point.
It happens that, PHPStorm detect an incoming connection, and asks me to accept the connection.
I click on accept, the debug fills with the variables and after 1 second, the connection stops and the debugging session ends.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you enable x debug port in your container ? (with the -p option) By default, x debug uses the port 9000

Comment: the port 9000 is opened by PHPStorm on the host, the connection is outgoing from xdebug (in the container) to phpstorm (on the machine). For this reason I don't think I need to expose the port 9000. Don't you think so?

Comment: I think it deserves a try, not 100% sure it's the solution but I have no other idea :\

Comment: just tried, it doesn't work :(

Comment: If I check "RUN -> break at the first line in PHP scripts" in PHPStorm the debug will stop on the first script, but if I press continue (the green arrow) it "doesn't detect" the other breakpoints

Comment: @AndreaGiuliano *"...but if I press continue ..."* This most likely means that IDE cannot map local path to remote one. Check your path mappings. It can also be that path on remote (inside docker container) uses symlinks -- xdebug works with final/resolved paths only. Therefore -- collect xdebug logs -- http://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#remote_log

Comment: For reference purposes: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-30084

Comment: @LazyOne thanks, it was me :P

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to get `xdebug.remote_connect_back=1` to work for me.

Instead, you need to provide the IP address of the docker host. Since the docker 18.03 release, you can reference the `host.docker.internal` DNS entry from within running docker containers.

You should try the following:

1. Remove the `xdebug.remote_connect_back=1` line. The default value is 0.
2. Add `xdebug.remote_host=host.docker.internal`

The rest of your steps sound correct.